# Merging Various Rows

Tags: tables

I am trying to merge the first three rows of the table, but unable to do. Example is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{caption}


\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\definecolor{tablecolor}{named}{cyan}

\NewEnviron{rndtable}[1]{%
  \addtolength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}%
  \rowcolors{2}{tablecolor!20}{tablecolor!40}%
  \sffamily%
  \newcommand{\header}[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{%
      \cellcolor{tablecolor}\color{white}\bfseries##1}}
  \savebox{\tablebox}{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
      \BODY%
    \end{tabular}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip[rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
    \node at (0,-\dp\tablebox) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\tablebox}};
    \draw[tablecolor,very thick,rounded corners=1ex] (0,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,-\dp\tablebox) -- (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox) -- (0,\ht\tablebox) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Caption}
\footnotesize{
\begin{rndtable}{lp{3cm}p{5cm} ll} %  
  \header{C} &
  \header{V} &
  \header{T} &
  \header{F} &

    \textbf{A} & C & G & A\\
  \textbf{B} & B  & M & A\\
  \textbf{B} & E & 1B & I \\
  \textbf{I} & M & N & A \\
  \textbf{M} & E & 12 & I \\
  \textbf{N} & E & NA    & NA \\
  \textbf{P} & I & P  & An \\
  \textbf{S} & B & C  & A \\
    \multicolumn{4}{l} {\footnotesize \textcolor{red} {Source: Central banks
\end{rndtable}}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me, what you mean with "merging the first three rows", but the example lets several issues to fix and improve, e.g.:

- Unmatched/wrongly matched curly braces, e.g. after Central banks are two
  closing braces missing.
- `\\` is missing after the header line.
- Only four columns are used, but five specified.
- Clipping should probably apply to the table, not the border line.
- The horizontal centered headers looked a little odd, thus I have changed it
  to left-aligned as the rest of the columns.
- Paths with the form of a rectangle can be defined using `rectangle`. Thus
  only two pairs of coordinates need to be specified, the lower left and upper right corner.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{caption}

\newsavebox{\tablebox}
\definecolor{tablecolor}{named}{cyan}

\NewEnviron{rndtable}[1]{%
  \addtolength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}%
  \rowcolors{2}{tablecolor!20}{tablecolor!40}%
  \sffamily
  \newcommand{\header}[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{%
      \cellcolor{tablecolor}%
      \color{white}%
      \bfseries##1%
    }%
  }%
  \savebox{\tablebox}{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
      \BODY
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip[rounded corners=1ex]
        (0,-\dp\tablebox) rectangle (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox);
      \node at (0,-\dp\tablebox) [anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt]
            {\usebox{\tablebox}};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[tablecolor,very thick,rounded corners=1ex]
      (0,-\dp\tablebox) rectangle (\wd\tablebox,\ht\tablebox);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Caption}
\footnotesize
\begin{rndtable}{lp{3cm}p{5cm} l} %  
  \header{C} &
  \header{V} &
  \header{T} &
  \header{F} \\
    \textbf{A} & C & G & A\\
  \textbf{B} & B  & M & A\\
  \textbf{B} & E & 1B & I \\
  \textbf{I} & M & N & A \\
  \textbf{M} & E & 12 & I \\
  \textbf{N} & E & NA    & NA \\
  \textbf{P} & I & P  & An \\
  \textbf{S} & B & C  & A \\
    \multicolumn{4}{l} {\footnotesize \textcolor{red} {Source: Central banks}}
\end{rndtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]